# Calculation with Alphanumeric characters

Tags: excel

I have data in cells A1:G1 like this: r2, r5, r7, r8, l4, l10, r20.
So my data has either "r" or "l" at beginning of each value.

I'd like to carry out an operation like this. Find the values in a range(A1:G1) containing "r" (if there are any), and then take the difference between the max value and min value.

So in this example: Max value with r is 20,
                    Min value with r is 2

Difference would be: r20 - r2 = r18

How can I achieve this in excel? Thanks for your help.

Note: I need a solution keeping the letter "r" in the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this array formula (finished with ctrl+shift+enter instead of just enter)

```
 ="R" & MAX(IF(LEFT(A1:G1)="R", --MID(A1:G1, 2, 99))) - MIN(IF(LEFT(A1:G1)="R", --MID(A1:G1, 2, 99)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Pierre44; that's a very valid addition.

Comment: Well thank you! I m the one learning from you all the time :)

Comment: Personally, I would just use a custom number format of `\r0` and forget all this text parsing nonsense but that wasn't the OP's question.

Comment: yeah, but he doesn't only have "r" he also has "l" for some reason.

Comment: Thanks alot, Jeeped.